# php 500 server error external conection

Tags: php, oop

Im trying to make a simple send text message (using API),the api's guys gave me an example codes,
this is the code:

```
function sentit() {
    $wsclient   = new SoapClient("xxxx", array('encoding' => 'UTF-8'));

    $s          = new Sms();
    $s->source  = "123";
    $s->message = "msg";

    $p1         = new Phone();
    $p1->phone  = 123456789;
    $p1->id     = "externalid1";

    $s->destinations = array($p1);

    $response   = $wsclient->sendSms("xx","xx", $s);
}
return sentit();
```

one more example them gives me:

```
<?
$url = "https://xxxx/api";
$xml ='
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sms>
<user>
<username>xxx</username>
<password>xxx</password>
</user>
<source>019</source>
<destinations>
<phone id=”someid1”>5xxxxxxx</phone>
<phone id=”someid2”>5xxxxxxx</phone>
</destinations>
<message>This is an example</message>
</sms>';

$CR = curl_init();
curl_setopt($CR, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($CR, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($CR, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true); curl_setopt($CR, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml); curl_setopt($CR, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); curl_setopt($CR,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array("charset=utf-8"));
$result = curl_exec($CR);
$error = curl_error ($CR);
if(!empty( $error )) die("Error: ".$error);
else
$response = new SimpleXMLElement($result);
?>
```

I have try to debug my SoapClient, no error, 
only when I write some var and make an new array the "500 error" happens

error log:

> [Thu Feb 25 23:11:14 2016] [warn] [client IP] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Sms' not found in /var/www/vhosts/x/..../sms_sender.php on line 11

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide the full code of your script. It seems that the class `Sms` is missing.

Comment: You probably need to reference the full namespace to the class.

Comment: $wsclient = new SoapClient("https://www.019sms.co.il/soap?wsdl",array(
'encoding' => 'UTF-8'));

Comment: have you tried to change the URL to IP addres?

Comment: propoblie the problem is PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Sms' not found
but i dont know how to declare the class vars...